# SourceTree shows no history

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a Git project in Bitbucket and I am running into an issue where I am not able too see commit history. I can check-in code and push it into the repo, but I am not able to see any changes. However, if I use the site or other Git visual client, I can see the commits. Any idea what I am doing wrong? SourceTree version 1.5.4.

Comment: I had this problem occasionally, and found restarting source tree, or removing, and re-adding the bookmark fixed it for me

Comment: I tried the same. I cloned the repo from scratch, upgraded from 1.5.3 to 1.5.4, but at no vail. Anything else that you have tried?

Comment: no - that did it for me. sorry

Comment: That would be a question for https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE

Comment: After contacting Atlassian support, we have been able to get to the bottom of it. There was a bug in the SourceTree app (see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1264). The problem was related to having .git/HEAD file in the root folder of the repository. New version (1.5.6) of the app should have this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Atlassian support, we have been able to get to the bottom of it. There was a bug in the SourceTree app (see [this JIRA issue](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1264)). The problem was related to having .git/HEAD file in the root folder of the repository. New version (1.5.6) of the app should have this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked assume-unchanged ??

use git **ls-files -v**. If the character printed is lower-case, the file is marked assume-unchanged.

Then use **git update-index --no-assume-unchanged --path/to files** to see them in commit